# C++ compile-time type checking

Tags: c++, templates

Was wondering if it's possible to have a template function that can branch depending on whether the type is derived from a particular class. Here's roughly what I'm thinking:

```
class IEditable {};

class EditableThing : public IEditable {};

class NonEditableThing {};

template<typename T>
RegisterEditable( string name ) {
    // If T derives from IEditable, add to a list; otherwise do nothing - possible?
}


int main() {
    RegisterEditable<EditableThing>( "EditableThing" );  // should add to a list
    RegisterEditable<NonEditableThing>( "NonEditableThing" );  // should do nothing
}
```

If anyone has any ideas let me know! :)

Edit: I should add, I don't want to instantiate / construct the given object just to check its type.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html

Comment: Interesting - will check that out, sounds promising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an implementation with `std::is_base_of`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void RegisterEditable( string name ) {
    if ( std::is_base_of<IEditable, T>::value ) {
        // add to the list
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - just got my head wrapped around type_traits, that does what I was looking for. Unfortunately it lead to another problem in the design I was thinking of, but I'll see if I can sort that out separately.

Answer (score 2):

As @Lightness noted, type_traits are the answer.

C++11 has included that `boost` type_trait: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of